# RabbitMQ memory usage creeping up and blocking calls... why?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm using RabbitMQ to handle app logs (windows server 2008 install). apps send messages to the exchange. I have a dedicated queue that gets messages forwarded to it. I then have a windows service connecting to that queue, pulling messages off, and persisting them to DB. I have a n-number of clients connecting to the exchange in real time to latch on the the stream so there are n-number of connections at a time. It is possible that some of these clients may not Close() their connections in code. Many clients have long running connections.

As messages are pulled off the queue, they are auto-ack'ed, so I don't have any unacknowledged messages on the queue. However, I'm seeing the memory of Rabbit grow over time. It starts at 32K or so when first turned on then creeps up until it exceeds the threshold and blocks incoming connections.

I have both .NET and Java clients--but both are auto-ack.

Reading the docs, I didn't see any description of how Rabbit is using memory--i.e. I don't understand why memory would be bloating over time. The messages are getting pulled off and ack'ed which seems to me would mean that Rabbit wouldn't be holding on to it any more and thus can free the associated memory, causing a stable mem usage profile.

I don't see how fiddling with the memory dial in Rabbit would help either--usage just creeps upwards over time: eventually I'll exceed it.

My guess is that there is something I'm doing wrong with my clients that is causing the memory to grow over time, but I can't think of why that would be.

```
 why does Rabbit memory usage creep up when no messages are kept on any queues? 

 what coding practices could cause the RabbitMQ server to 
 retain (and grow) memory?
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you have other queues bound to the exchange perhaps?  Check the Rabbit admin page under exchanges, click on your exchange, and check for queues bound to it.  It may be that one of your clients, when declaring the exchange, is inadvertently binding an unnamed (system random named) queue to the exchange, and messages are piling up in there.

The other thing to check is the QoS settings - if you leave QoS set at the default (infinite) then Rabbit will send out messages immediately to any client regardless of how many messages they are already holding.  This results in a lot of book-keeping, like which client has which message on the server, and a large buffer on the client.

Make sure to set your QoS pre-fetch limit to something much more reasonable, like say 100.  That way, if you have 1M messages and only 1 client with prefetch of 100, Rabbit will send only 100 to the client and keep the other 999900 on disk on the server, and not use nearly as much memory.

This was a big cause of memory bloat in my application, and now that I've addressed prefetch, everything is fine.

Comment: @ metaforge: thanks for the suggestion. Nope, that's not happening.